# VolleyError: java.lang.RuntimeException: Bad URL

Tags: java, android, request, android-volley

After making a second network request using Volley, I always get this error. It doesn't seem to matter what the url I put in is. Volley always claims it is malformed.

```
   try {
    RequestQueue queue = Volley.newRequestQueue(getActivity());
    StringRequest sr = new StringRequest(Request.Method.GET, "﻿http://27.67.80.6:18080/154.m3u8?AdaptiveType=HLS&VOD_RequestID=U6tIRX+QtmFBXhLTgqa7ueyBtmHx5QAI3mRpdZ2Q7ux7K53vZQMpmfIQhMqTkuSfjDtGu7YlgP0t/EorYPdiLw==", new Response.Listener<String>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(String response) {
          Log.e("Data",""+response);
        }

    }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
            Log.e("Loi",""+error);

        }
    }) {
        @Override
        protected Map<String, String> getParams() {
            Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<String, String>();
            params.put("DNT","1");
            return params;
        }


    };

    queue.add(sr);
} catch (Exception e) {

}
```

And then I see following error:

```
com.android.volley.VolleyError: java.lang.RuntimeException: Bad URL ﻿http://27.67.80.6:18080/154.m3u8?AdaptiveType=HLS&VOD_RequestID=U6tIRX+QtmFBXhLTgqa7ueyBtmHx5QAI3mRpdZ2Q7ux7K53vZQMpmfIQhMqTkuSfjDtGu7YlgP0t/EorYPdiLw==
```

Does anyone have any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Try using another URL, the URL you are using gives the following error!

[image]

Comment: thank support. url time out, please get url to http://live.tivi4k.net/nextbest.php?id=vtv1&token=rvotUCNR0weHhEHeZGkYPQ&e=1524075624 , I think that my urls contain special characters and port unto 18080, Does anyone have any ideas?

Comment: no port number does not matter as far as I know, but if you are using an URL which returns a JSON so better check your URL first before requesting it in the app!

Comment: no, While I do not use the library, the same error java.net.MalformedURLException: Protocol not found

Comment: which URL are you using now?

Comment: i gettings url to http://live.tivi4k.net/nextbest.php?id=vtv1&token=rvotUCNR0weHhEHeZGkYPQ&e=1524075624

Comment: no, get url data in url http://live.tivi4k.net/nextbest.php?id=vtv1&token=rvotUCNR0weHhEHeZGkYPQ&e=1524075624

Comment: just try with a simple API which returns a JSON data like: *http://ip.jsontest.com/*